# What is the correct way for async IO in F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#

Lets assume we have the following C# method

```cs
public async Task DoStuffAsync(string path)
{
    var fullPath = Path.Combine(
        Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
        path
    );

    using var stream = File.OpenText(fullPath);

    while (!stream.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = await stream.ReadLineAsync();
                 
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(line);
    }
}
```

and we want to implement this in F#, my first attempt was to code it like this

```
let doStuffAsync path =
    async {
        let fullPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), path)

        use stream = File.OpenText fullPath

        while (not stream.EndOfStream) do
            let! line = stream.ReadLineAsync() |> Async.AwaitTask
            System.Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(line) |> Async.AwaitTask |> ignore
    }
```

but that does not seam right to me as we have to unpack a `Task<string>` into a `Async<string>` then unpack this. Same for the `Task` from `WriteLineAsync`.

Are there no F# variantes for the methods `ReadLineAsync` and `WriteLineAsync` which return `Async<_>` instead of `Task<_>`?

Also is there somekind of async pipe operaor that would let me do

```
stream.ReadLineAsync() 
|> Async.AwaitTask
|> System.Console.Out.WriteLineAsync
|> Async.AwaitTask
|> ignore
```

Comment: `let! x = someTask |> Async.AwaitTask` is totally right in F#, nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

The use of `Async.AwaitTask` is correct as @NghiaBui pointed out.  These are two async models and you need to convert in between them.

I'm afraid there are no `Async<'T>` variants of `ReadlineAsync` and most .net core libraries.

You could use  [TaskBuilder](https://github.com/rspeele/TaskBuilder.fs) for some cleaner syntax:

```
task {

  let fullPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), path)

  use stream = File.OpenText fullPath
  while (not stream.EndOfStream) do
     let! line = stream.ReadLineAsync() 
     do! System.Console.Out.WriteLineAsync line      
}
```

Regarding the piping, I'm afraid it's not possible.  There are some [discussions](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/791) to bring in a `|>!` operator but it looks like it would add more complexity than it's necessary.